# NotSerializableException on saving custom class

Tags: java, serialization, notserializableexception

My two classes are designed too create an array of StudentData objects (name, Date Of Birth, and ID), that include a toString override to print out all variables. It then serializes the array  and saves it to a file named studentdata.txt. It should then read the array from the file and reconstruct a new array object from this data, and print out each item in the array to the console.

Am getting this error when attempting to complie...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.NotSerializableException: Student
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at StudentData.main(StudentData.java:38)
```

Also am not sure how to properly loop through my array and call my toString method to print out to the console, would i be right in assuming I should use a for each loop? Like this?

```
                 //for (Student s : ???) {
                  //System.out.println(How do I call toString from here?);
```

My classes

```
import java.io.*;         //importing input-output files
    class Student
    {


   String name;                     //declaration of variables
 String DOB;
   int id;



   Student(String naam,int idno, String dob)          //Initialising variables to user data
   { 
          name=naam;
          id=idno;
          DOB=dob;

    }

   public String toString() {
       return name+"\t"+id+"\t"+DOB+"\t";
}



}
```

Number 2

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

class StudentData                     //main class
{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException                  //exception handling
  {
         System.out.println("Enter the numbers of students:");
         BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
         int n=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());


         Student[]  S=new Student[n];                      // array of objects declared and defined
         for (int i = 0; i < S.length; i++)       {

               System.out.println("Enter the Details of Student no: "+(i+1));             //reading data form the user
               System.out.println("Name: ");
               String naam=in.readLine();
               System.out.println("ID no: ");
               int idno=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
               System.out.println("DOB: ");               
               String dob=(in.readLine());


              S[i]=new Student(naam,idno,dob);                          

              File studentFile = new File("StudentData.txt");
              try {
              FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(studentFile);
              ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutput);
              objectOutput.writeObject(S);

              S = null;

              FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(studentFile);
              ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInput);

                S = (Student[]) objectInputStream.readObject();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

              //for (Student s : ???) {
                  //System.out.println();
              }

         }








     }
```

Comment: Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get rid of the `NotSerializableException: Student` exception, just make your `Student` class implement the [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface.  (Note that this is a marker interface, so you don't have to implement any methods.)

```
class Student implements Serializable {
}
```

---

To loop through the array `S` of `Student` objects, try this:

```
for (Student st : S) {
    System.out.println(st);
}
```

I'd pick a more descriptive name for the array though (`students` would be better).  If you declare the array as

```
Student[]  students = new Student[n];
```

then your for loop can be more readable.

```
for (Student student : students) {
    System.out.println(student);
}
```

Note that you don't have to explicitly call the `toString` method on an object of type `Student`.  Java will do that implicitly for you when you use an object as the parameter to a method that expects a `String`.

Comment: Thanks the help! 
I understand how importatnt it is for code to be read-able...makes it easier for everyone then!

Answer (score 2):

Your class `Student` should implement [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface to make its instances `serializable`.

Edit your `Student` class declaration to: -

```
class Student implements java.io.Serializable {
}
```

See this link: - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html  It talkes in detail about `Serialization`.

Answer (score 1):

implement your Student class   java.io.Serializable interface.